# wxPython - wx.TextCtrl - forcing styles

Tags: python, styles, wxpython, textctrl, wx.textctrl

just a simple question on a wx.TextCtrl element. 
i have this text field where on an application, where the user can add a string on it. 
i want a text field with a red text on it. 
so i've generated this code:

```
self.hRepositoryTextfield = wx.TextCtrl(self.hPanel)
self.hRepositoryTextfield.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.RED))
```

if the user copy on this text field some string with applied font on it (for example a black coloured string, or a string with a particular font) the red color, anyway the default style is not respected. 
i would like the style i decide for my wx.TextCtrl is always forced according my settings. 
how can i do?

thank you in advance

axel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem in this way:

in the first part of the code it is defined my textfield style...

```
self.hRepositoryTextfield.SetStyle(0, len(self.hRepositoryTextfield.GetValue()), wx.TextAttr(wx.RED))
self.hRepositoryTextfield.SetFont(self.hFontLabel)
self.hRepositoryTextfield.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.forceDefaultStyle)
```

... then i bind every text change to my forcing-style function:

```
def forceDefaultStyle(self, event):
    hEventObject = event.GetEventObject()
    hEventObject.SetStyle(0, len(self.hRepositoryTextfield.GetValue()), wx.TextAttr(wx.RED))
    hEventObject.SetFont(self.hFontLabel)
```

and it works!

Answer (score 1):

The SetForegroundColor might work on one OS and not on another. It depends on the native widget. I would set the TextCtrl's style flag to wx.TE_RICH. Check out the wxPython demo for an example. You can also use the StyledTextCtrl or FancyText of even the HTMLCtrl.

Comment: +1 just cause Mike knows his wxPython better than just about anyone else on SO ...

Comment: i'm a newbie on python, so sorry for my question, but i don't understand @mike-driscoll what should i do with the flag wx.TE_RICH.

`self.hRepositoryTextfield = wx.TextCtrl(self.hPanel, style=wx.TE_RICH)
self.hRepositoryTextfield.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.RED))` 

are my new commands, but if i copy on my TextCtrl some text with other font or style, they won't be displayed in red as i would expect them to be. i will try with FancyText or your other suggestions.

Comment: one more question. is there a way to write something like
`self.hRepositoryTextfield.Bind(wx.EVT_????, self.setMyDefaultStyle)`
because i don't understand if there's a Event for wx.TextCtrl changes

Comment: The wxPython demo shows how to do it. When you create the text control you pass it the style=wx.TE_RICH. Then you use the SetStyle method to change a string of text to a different color.

Comment: i didn't know the existence of wxPython Demo package... thanks a lot, if i will have any problem I'll tell you, otherwise, good programming to all.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.hRepositoryTextfield.SetForegroundColor(wx.RED)
```

that should work ....

Comment: mac osx 10.5.8 / python 2.7 / wx 2.8

Comment: Oh Im on windows... not sure I woulda thought it would work on mac but guess not :/